# Unit testing Angular directive that consumes services

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine

I have a directive that consumes a service:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.service('myService', function() {
  return {
    getCustomer: function(){
      return {
        name: 'Naomi',
        address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
      };
    }
  };
})
.directive('myCustomer', function(myService) {
  return {
    link: function(scope){
      scope.customer = myService.getCustomer();
    },

    template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
  };
});
```

I'm trying to unit test this, but I can't seem to figure out how to inject the service into my directive in the unit test.

```
var tests;
(function (tests) {
    describe('myCustomer Directive', function () {
        var scope, createDirective;

        beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));
        beforeEach(angular.mock.module('templates'));

        beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
            var $compile = $injector.get('$compile');

            var myService = $injector.get('myService');

            scope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

            // where do I inject myService???

            createDirective = function () {
                return $compile('<my-customer></my-customer>')(scope);
            };
        }));
        describe('on creation', function () {
            var sut;

            beforeEach(function () {
                sut = createDirective();
                scope.$digest();
            });

            it('creates an element node', function () {
                var contents = sut.contents();
                expect(contents[0].nodeType).toBe(sut[0].ELEMENT_NODE);
            });
        });
    });
})(tests || (tests = {}));
```

The problem is that I need to be able to explicitly inject the dependency so I can mock some of it's calls.  Is this possible?

[Here's a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JoLBRsqWFxLyxny5RoxT?p=preview) with my app code.

Comment: You don't need to inject it. Angular injects it for you.

Comment: That's the problem: It's not.  I'm getting an unknown provider error.

Comment: If you have an error, post the complete error message/stacktrace in the question.

Comment: Well turns out the unknown provider error was unrelated, but I still need to be able to explicitly inject the dependency so I can mock it.

Comment: Don't mock it. Spy on it. The end result is the same, but it's easier.

Comment: That works!   Didn't know creating an instance of that service and spying on it would take care of everything.  Thanks!

Comment: When asking the injector for the service, you don't *create* an instance of the service. You get the unique instance of the service, shared by all the components where it's injected. That's why it works. BTW, instead of injecting the injector, and asking the service to the injector, you could (and should) inject the service itself.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out, as JB Nizet pointed out, that all you need to do is spy on the service and it all takes care of itself.

```
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
        var $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
        scope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

        var myService = $injector.get('myService');

        // set up spies
        spyOn(myService, "getCustomer").and.returnValue({foo: 'bar'});

        createDirective = function () {
            return $compile('<my-customer></my-customer>')(scope);
        };
    }));
```